# Never allow two elements to split CSS3 Columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm having trouble keeping two elements "together" using CSS3 columns. Consider the following HTML:

```
<div style="column-count: 2"> <!-- I'm aware there's more CSS rules needed -->
    <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>
    <div class="content">Long paragraph text goes in here lalalalala</div>
    <div class="heading">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="content">Some longer paragraph text goes in here</div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, Firefox and Safari this displays as I would like it to:

```
Heading 1                 | Heading 2
Long paragraph text goes  | Some longer paragraph text goes
in here lalalalala        | in here
```

I've used the following CSS to "stick" the heading and the content `<div>`s together:

```
.heading {padding-bottom: 30px;}
.content {margin-top: -30px;}
```

This ensures that the heading is not the last item in one column, with the content in the next column. However this is exactly what happens in IE10:

```
Heading 1                 | Some longer paragraph text goes
Long paragraph text goes  | in here
in here lalalalala        | 
Heading 2                 |
```

Keep in mind that there can be many `#heading` and `#content` divs in each column, so it's not enough to simply use a `break-after: always` on the heading.

Also, it's not enough to wrap both elements in another div and add `break-inside: avoid;` on that div, because `#content` divs have to be able to flow between columns.

What I'm after is some CSS to ensure that the heading and content div don't get split up at the column break.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting matching headers and content into one `<section>` tag?

Comment: Yep, just tried that, makes no difference

Comment: You should be able to use `break-after:avoid` on the headers.

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your divs ...remains constant.  I am breaking every two divs into their own columns, less additional formatting per your project scope (i.e. padding, etc.).

## HTML

```
<div style="column-count: 2" id="columns"> <!-- I'm aware there's more CSS rules needed -->
    <div class="heading menuitem">Heading 1</div>
    <div class="content menuitem">Long paragraph text goes in here lalalalala</div>
    <div class="heading menuitem">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="content menuitem">Some longer paragraph text goes in here</div>
    <div class="heading menuitem">Heading 3</div>
    <div class="content menuitem">Some longer paragraph text goes in here</div>
    <div class="heading menuitem">Heading 4</div>
    <div class="content menuitem">Some longer paragraph text goes in here</div>    
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.menuitem{
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 200px;  height: 300px; 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
.menuitem:nth-child(4n+1), .menuitem:nth-child(4n+2){
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/V99cT/

---

If you want the headers in the columns AND assuming you can edit your HTML, use this:

```
<div style="column-count: 2" id="columns"> <!-- I'm aware there's more CSS rules needed -->
    <div class="content menuitem"><h1>Heading 1</h1>Long paragraph text goes in here lalalalala</div>
    <div class="content menuitem"><h1>Heading 2</h1>Long paragraph text goes in here lalalalala</div>
    <div class="content menuitem"><h1>Heading 3</h1>Long paragraph text goes in here lalalalala</div>
    <div class="content menuitem"><h1>Heading 4</h1>Long paragraph text goes in here lalalalala</div>    
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.menuitem{
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 200px;  height: 300px; 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:top;
   padding: 20px;
}
.menuitem:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #3c3c3c;

}
```

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RRfTV/

Comment: The heading a content divs need to be below each other, not next to other

Comment: @MichaelBates is the HTML set or can you modify it?

Comment: @MichaelBates updated code to allow heading and content to be stacked.  This is assuming you can just use a Header tag instead of a DIV for header.

Comment: I can fully edit the HTML. However the headers and content need to flow on one from the other (not each heading in a new column)